# Excude value from sql results

Tags: mysql, database

Here is my problem.I have a table with recursive association like this:(#id_boss,#id_manager) that references id_employee.

I have a function with $id argument .In that function i have an sql query that should return the id_boss or id_manager depending on $id.

This is my query:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT (id_guy, id_friend)
from table
where id_guy=$id || id_friend=$id;
```

My query works well but returns the $id value too (because id_guy could be $id_friend for another $id_guy) which i would like to exclude.

Example:

- $id_guy=10, id_friend=11
- $id_guy=14, id_friend=10

I would like to have this as result: 11,14 
and not: 10,11,14,10

How could i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` ignores `NULL` values, so you can just use a `case` in the `select`:

```
select group_concat((case when id_guy <> $id then id_guy end),
                    (case when id_friend <> $id then id_friend end)
                   )
from table
where $id in (id_guy, id_friend);
```

EDIT:

The above might require an `else`:

```
select group_concat((case when id_guy <> $id then id_guy else '' end),
                    (case when id_friend <> $id then id_friend else '' end)
                   )
from table
where $id in (id_guy, id_friend);
```

Comment: I have a NULL result when i try it. I don't understand why since your logic is good